# Attempted to call an undefined method named "arrayNode"

Tags: php, symfony, configuration

I have this config in `config.yml` file in my Symfony 3.5 project:

```
my_config:
    token: mHSHlSHl-QqSHlX-SHlQqShzO2ibzGnsNk-Q
    username: test

    development:
        developers_id: [130]
        maintenance:
            enable: true
            text: "text of text"
```

I have a bundle to parse this config in my `configuration.php` file. In the bundle dependency injection I have this code:

```
$treeBuilder = new TreeBuilder();
$rootNode = $treeBuilder->root('my_bundle');
$rootNode->children()
    ->scalarNode("username")
    ->end()
    ->scalarNode("token")
        ->isRequired()
    ->end()
    ->arrayNode('development')
        ->children()
            ->booleanNode('send_log')
                ->defaultFalse()
            ->end()
            ->arrayNode('developers_id')
                ->prototype('scalar')
            ->end()
            ->arrayNode('maintenance')
                ->children()
                    ->booleanNode('enable')
                        ->defaultFalse()
                    ->end()
                    ->scalarNode('text')
                        ->defaultValue('default text')
                    ->end()
                ->end()
            ->end()
        ->end()
    ->end()
->end();

return $treeBuilder;
```

When I run this code I get this error:

> Attempted to call an undefined method named "arrayNode" of class
>   "Symfony\Component\Config\Definition\Builder\ArrayNodeDefinition".

What should I do?

Comment: Try clearing your cache (`cache:clear [--env=...] [--no-debug]`), if that doesn't help: Break up the code right before the line that throws the error and dump `$rootNode` at that point to see it's type.

Comment: @ccKep I can't run commands because i get error

Comment: you ran just remove cache with rm -rf var/cache

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I get this error because after `->prototype('scalar')` I didn't write `->end()`, I added `->end()` and my problem was solved.

the right syntax is like this:

```
->arrayNode('developers_id')    
    ->prototype('scalar')
    ->end()
->end()
```